# Execute bash script via ansible playbook

Tags: bash, unix, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I'm looking to run the following shell script via ansible playbook.

```
#!/bin/bash
oci compute instance list --lifecycle-state RUNNING --region ca-toronto-1 --compartment-id < compartment OCID> --all | grep display-name -A 0 > hostnames.txt
for line in `cat hostnames.txt`
  do
   #echo $line
   if [[ $line == *","* ]]; then
    #    hostname=$(echo ${line//"display-name"/} | tr -d '",: ')
        hostname=$(echo "$line" | tr -d '",')
        echo "$hostname"
        ssh -tt "$hostname" "sudo puppet agent -tv && sleep 10"
       # break
   fi
  done
```

This works just like how i want when i run the shell script but I get a blank output when i run via ansible.
Playbook:

```
---
- name: puppet agent trigger
  gather_facts: false
  become_user: true
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: trigger puppet agent
      shell: |
        oci compute instance list --lifecycle-state RUNNING --region ca-toronto-1 --compartment-id <compartment OCID> --all | grep display-name -A 0 > hostnames.txt
        for line in `cat hostnames.txt`
        do
        if [[ $line == *","* ]]; then
         hostname=$(echo "$line" | tr -d '",')
         echo "$hostname"
         ssh -tt "$hostname" "sudo puppet agent -tv && sleep 10"
        fi
        done
      register: shell_output

    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ shell_output.stdout }}"
```

Please point me as to what im missing.

Comment: There is a [script module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/script_module.html) that executes scripts. Since your script works independently, you could try this instead of `shell` with in-line script.

Comment: Ansible uses a non login non interactive sh (default) shell. This does not load any init filles (e.g. bashrc, login...)

Comment: Separate from what others have correctly said, the very idea of using `shell:` inside ansible to _generate a machine inventory_ so you can _connect to them via ssh_ and _run some command on them_ is some chef's kiss level "you are solving the wrong problem"; do you perhaps need to read about [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html)?

Comment: As an aside, [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). There is a tool http://shellcheck.net/ which can point out this and many other beginner errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the description of your use case it seems to be recommended to transfer the whole logic of the script into Ansible itself. To do so and in respect to the comment regarding [`add_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html)_module, you could use an approach like

```
- name: Create an instance list
  shell:
    cmd: oc get nodes --no-headers | cut -d " " -f 1 | tr '\n' "," | rev | cut -c 2- | rev 
  register: instance_list
  changed_when: false
```

To generate the `instance_list` I've used an OpenShift cluster as example, because I don't have something like `oci compute instance list ...` accessible.

```
- name: Add all hosts from instance_list to the script group
  add_host:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    groups: script
  loop: "{{ instance_list }}"
```

From there you could proceed further to execute your command `puppet agent -tv && sleep 10`.

Comment: Thanks this is great! Should i add another task to run my puppet command and iterate it in the loop?

Comment: Right @karthick, from there you need to add further tasks for `("script" in group_names)`.

Comment: Thanks! Made it work.. Is there a way to get the consolidated o/p at the end as to which host passed/failed?